# Is there a new Heap memory create each time ,when we typecast JsonNode to ObjectNode and insert?

Tags: java, json, memory, jackson

I have a new JsonNode that I created

```
JsonNode json = new ObjectCodec().createObjectNode();
```

put new attributes to this json

```
((ObjectNode) json).put("fname","first");
((ObjectNode) json).put("lname","last");
```

Comment: No. A typecast does not create a new object.

Comment: Type cast - no, it doesn't. Insert (method put()) - yes, you can look into https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.java#L730 and deeper. Also, you allocate new memory to prepare arguments (immutable String-s). If you are worrying about memory allocation/gc, you could take a look at a small lib https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly which is GC-free